# Synonym for word "Administration"

Tags: synonyms

Can anyone give me synonym for "*Administration*"?

I am using a software that has "*Administration*" as a keyword, so it doesn't allow any use of this word.

However, My task is to create a folder for each department of some enterprise (and it has an Administration Department).

My question Here is: How can I find a synonym for "*Administration*" without losing the real meaning of the term?

> P.S.: I found synonyms like "administrative" and "directors"  which don't fit in my context.

Comment: http://thesaurus.com/browse/administration May have some words to suit your needs

Comment: Can you get away with 'admin'?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Nope

Comment: Are _all_ abbreviated forms barred?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth indeed yes

Comment: If the department name is "Administration Department", it doesn't seem intuitive to change that.  How about changing the keyword to AD_MIN or something like that?

Comment: Or changing the software.

Comment: @KristinaLopez All abbreviated forms cannot be used in my case ... and i can't use "department" at the end either :/

Comment: in this context will be the use of "Direction" Correct?

Comment: *Governance*, *government*, or *governor*? *Management*?

Comment: What does the administration department do? General management or some other activities?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based upon the following, I think "management" would be a good fit:

> ad·min·is·ter
>   ədˈminəstər/Submit
>   verb
>   1. manage and be responsible for the running of (a business, organization, etc.).
>   "each school was administered separately"
>   synonyms: manage, direct, control, operate, regulate, conduct, handle, > run, organize, supervise, superintend, oversee, preside over, govern, rule, lead, head, steer; More
>   be responsible for the implementation or use of (law or resources).
>   "a federal agency would administer new regulations"